# When you use the PS1 code, the automation stops working

Tags: linux, bash, ps1

I need to color bash on multiple linux servers, I'm creating ps1_color.sh file in /etc/profile.d/ with code below:

`if [ "$PS1" ]; then PS1="\[\e[;32m\]*PRE-PROD* [\u@\h \W]\\$ \[\e[m\]" fi`

The problem is being in an automation that is used in some servers, they use an ssh.jar to loop access to several servers with a certain user and execute a command on these servers, however, every time I put this code in the PS1 it does not execute automation, when I remove or put the standard linux code on the PS1, it works normally.

What could be wrong with the code? Or does anyone have any other ideas of what might be going on?

All servers use Red Hat Enterprise in different versions.

thanks

I put the PS1 code without the if condition

Putting the default code `[\u@\h \W]\$` works normally

Comment: Try not colorizing the `$`: `PS1="... [\u@\h \W]\[\e[m\]\\$ "`

Comment: You need to look at your automation. Presumably it's doing something like trying to match a command prompt based on a regex; it's not a problem with the bash code you're showing us, but with the automation you _aren't_ showing us.

Comment: (btw, best practice is not to do that at all: good practice when doing automation is to run a lot of single-command channels over a longstanding transport instance; do that right and there's no interactive shell involved anywhere, and consequently no reason to try to regex-match what a prompt looks like; the advantages include inability to get confused when a command outputs something that _looks_ like a prompt, complete lack of ambiguity about which command any given stdout or stderr came from, ability to run multiple commands over the same transport without mixing their output, etc)